# Cocos2d-iPhone with Box2D: CCPhysicsSprite EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, objective-c++

I just recently started messing with cocos2d's Box2D integration, while most of the process has been simple and straight forward, I keep running into a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when using a CCPhysicsSprite (CCSprite subclass that integrates a b2body with the sprite). The code I'm using is:

```
- (void)spawnBallAtPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    count++;

    CCPhysicsSprite *sprite = [CCPhysicsSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 52, 52)];
    sprite.position = point;
    [self addChild:sprite];

    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(point.x / PTM_RATIO, point.y / PTM_RATIO);
    bodyDef.userData = sprite;
    b2Body *body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    b2CircleShape circleShape;
    circleShape.m_radius = (26.0 / PTM_RATIO);

    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &circleShape;
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.2f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.8f;
    body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

    sprite.b2Body = body;
}
```

This code triggers an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, I know it's the CCPhysicsSprite because changing CCPhysicsSprite to CCSprite throws zero errors:

```
- (void)spawnBallAtPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    count++;

    CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 52, 52)];
    sprite.position = point;
    [self addChild:sprite];

    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(point.x / PTM_RATIO, point.y / PTM_RATIO);
    bodyDef.userData = sprite;
    b2Body *body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    b2CircleShape circleShape;
    circleShape.m_radius = (26.0 / PTM_RATIO);

    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &circleShape;
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.2f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.8f;
    body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
}
```

I've been looking around and can't find a real answer (as all the sample code uses CCPhysicsSprite in this way without error). I'm sure I'm making a stupid mistake but I guess that's to be expected when learning something new :P

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: which line exactly gives bad access?

Comment: The method inline float32 b2Body::GetAngle() const in b2body, specifically return m_sweep.a;

Comment: But it's only when b2body is used on a CCPhysicsSprite, otherwise b2body throws no errors

Comment: there are no calls of b2Body::GetAngle() in the code you posted.

Comment: Look, code you posted doesn't show where the crash happens.

Comment: @Kreiri It's happening in the Box2d physics code... Something they are doing is choking up the engine.

Comment: were you able to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

With `CCPhysicsSprite` you must set the body BEFORE you set the position of the sprite.
I assume that this line is where the crash occurs:

```
sprite.position = point;
```

If you look at `CCPhysicsSprite` it overrides the position/setPosition to always use the values from the contained `b2body` object. So it really accesses its b2body property, which is `nil` at that point → Crash.
Generally after creating a CCPhysicsSprite you want to set its .b2body as soon as possible - there might be more occasions where similar problems might occur just because you need to set the .b2body property first.

So, move `sprite.position = point;` below `sprite.b2Body = body;`.

Comment: Also, you must pass the PTM_RATIO to the CCPhysicsSprite before setting its position: `physicsSprite.PTM_RATIO = ...;`

Comment: That's right. That's another pitfall I spent hours climbing up from.