# How to combine a physics body with tile sprites?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am working with tile map and box2d with cocos2D in the game for iOS, i want to move the tile with respect to physics bodies, i.e. to combine one or more tiles in a body and on contact if body is moving then tile sprites should also move. Please suggest something to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CCPhysicsSprite for this.

The following code is from the default Box2D project in Cocos2d v2.

```
-(void) addNewSpriteAtPosition:(CGPoint)p
{
    CCLOG(@"Add sprite %0.2f x %02.f",p.x,p.y);
    // Define the dynamic body.
    //Set up a 1m squared box in the physics world
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(p.x/PTM_RATIO, p.y/PTM_RATIO);
    b2Body *body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    // Define another box shape for our dynamic body.
    b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;
    dynamicBox.SetAsBox(.5f, .5f);//These are mid points for our 1m box

    // Define the dynamic body fixture.
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox;
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
    body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);


    CCNode *parent = [self getChildByTag:kTagParentNode];

    //We have a 64x64 sprite sheet with 4 different 32x32 images.  The following code is
    //just randomly picking one of the images
    int idx = (CCRANDOM_0_1() > .5 ? 0:1);
    int idy = (CCRANDOM_0_1() > .5 ? 0:1);
    CCPhysicsSprite *sprite = [CCPhysicsSprite spriteWithTexture:spriteTexture_ rect:CGRectMake(32 * idx,32 * idy,32,32)];
    [parent addChild:sprite];

    [sprite setPTMRatio:PTM_RATIO];
    [sprite setB2Body:body];
    [sprite setPosition: ccp( p.x, p.y)];

}
```

**NOTE** The position of the sprite has been set after the body has been created.  If you do it the other way around, you *may* get an exception.  [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327463/cocos2d-iphone-with-box2d-ccphysicssprite-exc-bad-access)